# Make parts of website unavailable without login

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, server

I am creating a game where you have two options: Play the game, and view global and local highscores. I have created a signup and login system. When you successfully log in, you can either 1. play game, 2. check highscores, and 3. log out.

I am hosting a server with nodejs. The problem is, one could easily put localhost:3000/menu to access the menu without logging in. How do I make the rest of the site unavailable if you are not logged in? This is the code I use to display the pages:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});

app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/signup.html'));
});

app.get('/menu', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/menu.html'));
});

app.get('/highscores', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/highscores.html'));
});

app.get('/main', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/main.html'));
});
```

My friend told me I could do something like this:

```
app.get('<username>/menu',
```

Is there a good way to implement this or are there better solutions?

Comment: If you're serious about your project, don't try reinventing the wheel. There are many libraries available which can achieve this, and are battle-tested by thousands of people, decreasing the chances of leaving a security hole. You should get started by typing ["authentication expressjs"](https://www.google.com/search?q=authentication+expressjs) in your favorite search engine. An important keyword: middleware

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know how your login system works, but if a user successfully log in, you should store a **token** that identify the user, and is unique. I recommend you [this video](https://youtu.be/2jqok-WgelIj) if this isn’t what you have done.

Then, when a user request the `/menu` route, you should check that there is a token in the local storage, or wherever you want to store it, and most inportantly, check that the token is valid, that it is not a fake one.

Comment: Thank you! If I was to follow the instructions in the video, do you reckon it would be possible to use PostgreSQL rather than MongoDB?

Comment: @Sergio I don’t know, but I am pretty sure it would be possible. I personally used MySQL, so I won’t see any problem for you to use PostgreSQL.